# How do I get the items selected from a QListView?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

```
{
...
    nrow = 10;     
    ncol = 1;

    /*create QListView */
    m_listView = new QListView(this);
    m_listView->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0,100), QSize(100, 150)));

    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel( nrow, 1, this );

    //fill model value
    for( int r=0; r<nrow; r++ )
    {
        QString sstr = "[ " + QString::number(r) + " ]";
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("Idx ") + sstr);
        model->setItem(r, 0, item);
    }

    //set model
    m_listView->setModel(model);
    m_listView->setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection );
    connect(m_listView, SIGNAL(pressed(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(hItem(QModelIndex)));
}

void MainWindow::hItem(QModelIndex m)
{
    QItemSelectionModel *selectionModel = m_listView->selectionModel();

    m_txt2->setText(QString::number(selectionModel->selectedIndexes().at(0),'d',0));//???

    //not sure how to get the items selected:  index and string per selection    
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just tested this for my own needs and it works in Qt 5.1.

I'm pretty new to C++ so in this line:

```
foreach(const QModelIndex &index, list){
```

I don't know if the `const` and the dereferencing (`&`) is needed - it works with or without. I cobbled this together from various examples I've seen.

Perhaps someone who understands C++ better can comment.

```
void MainWindow::on_keywordsList_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
   QModelIndexList list =keywordListView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();

   QStringList slist;
   foreach(const QModelIndex &index, list){
       slist.append( index.data(Qt::DisplayRole ).toString());
   }
   qDebug() << slist.join(",");
}
```

Comment: const ref is better. & makes it faster, const makes it safe against unintended modification of the original container.